# Break binary strings in SQL Server columns into individual bits in separate columns

Tags: sql-server, split

I have several columns of 8 bit strings (e.g., '01001000'). I'd like to break the string in each column into 8 columns, one for each bit.

Is there a cleaner way than copying and pasting `substring(str, n, 1)` a zillion times?

Note I'm subsequently going to group by another column and count the number of 1's for each separate bit position....in case that helps understanding.

Answer (score 1):

I think this may help:

```
CREATE TABLE tab123(B1 INT, B2 INT, B3 INT, B4 INT, B5 INT, B6 INT, B7 INT, B8 INT)

DECLARE @TAB VARCHAR(100) = '01001000',
     @VALUES VARCHAR(MAX) = 'INSERT INTO TAB123 SELECT '

SELECT @VALUES = @VALUES + VAL
   FROM
      (
         SELECT SUBSTRING(@TAB, NUMBER, 1) + ',' VAL
             FROM master.dbo.spt_values
             WHERE TYPE = 'P' AND NUMBER BETWEEN 1 AND LEN(@TAB)
      ) AS A

SELECT @VALUES = SUBSTRING(@VALUES, 1, LEN(@VALUES) - 1)

EXEC (@VALUES)

SELECT * FROM tab123

DROP TABLE tab123
```

Comment: hmm i think this is on the right track, but to be useful for several columns and nested in a larger query I need to be able to turn it into a function.  How would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Create a new table with 8 bit columns, then do an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` into this new table from your current table:

```
INSERT INTO newTable (b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6, b7, b8)
SELECT
    CAST(SUBSTRING(col, 1, 1) AS BIT),
    CAST(SUBSTRING(col, 2, 1) AS BIT),
    CAST(SUBSTRING(col, 3, 1) AS BIT),
    CAST(SUBSTRING(col, 4, 1) AS BIT),
    CAST(SUBSTRING(col, 5, 1) AS BIT),
    CAST(SUBSTRING(col, 6, 1) AS BIT),
    CAST(SUBSTRING(col, 7, 1) AS BIT),
    CAST(SUBSTRING(col, 8, 1) AS BIT)
FROM oldTable
```